# Magellan GPS stops recording data in suspend mode

Tags: gps

Currently having a problem with my Magellan Explorist 510 GPS unit. After I start recording the track on the unit, after some time, it just stops recording data in suspend mode (which should turn everything off *except* the tracking of GPS position on the track).

I don't know if it's a setting that I have changed or if it's a problem with the unit. Before I try a firmware reset, I was just wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue?

Comment: This may not be the cause of your problem but, if you hold down the on/off button for too long when switching out of suspend mode, it will reset the unit and your data will be lost.

Comment: I suspect that this question may be better researched/asked on [su] but check their on topic pages prior to making any post there.